# What should one do on encountering a frozen login screen after a suspend?

Tags: unity, login, suspend

After suspending my computer, I regularly encounter a login screen that is frozen. The mouse can be moved, but I cannot interact with anything such as the passcode field. What should I do when I encounter this?

I've tried going to another tty and running `unity --replace` but this just causes me to lose everything. I really want to know because I've lost work because of this.

Answer (score 0):

***Fisrt off I do not guarantee this will work; so use at your own risk.**

You First need to create a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`  It can be any name but to ensure the load order, use the `prefix 20_.`

Login as a root user and create a file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd  /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
```

Now you can insert this code int the file you have created.

```
 VERSION=1.1
    DEV_LIST=/tmp/usb-dev-list
    DRIVERS_DIR=/sys/bus/pci/drivers
    DRIVERS="ehci xhci" # ehci_hcd, xhci_hcd
    HEX="[[:xdigit:]]"
    MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=2
    BIND_WAIT=0.1


    unbindDev() {
    echo -n > $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
    for driver in $DRIVERS; do

    DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    for dev in `ls $DDIR 2>/dev/null | egrep "^$HEX+:$HEX+:$HEX"`; do
    echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/unbind
    echo "$driver $dev" >> $DEV_LIST

    done
    done
    }

    bindDev() {
    if [ -s $DEV_LIST ]; then
    while read driver dev; do
    DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    while [ $((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS)) -gt 0 ]; do
     echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/bind
    if [ ! -L "$DDIR/$dev" ]; then
    sleep $BIND_WAIT
    else
    break
    fi
    MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=$((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS-1))
    done
    done < $DEV_LIST
    fi
    rm $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
    }

    case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend) unbindDev;;
    resume|thaw)  bindDev;;
    esac
```

Now add executable permission:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
```

And Reboot... Suspend should work as expected...